Mapstruct can't resolve type T when using a generic Lombok @Builder (T cannot be resolved to a type)
I am using the following Lombok and Mapstruct version in my Spring Boot application:

Lombok 1.18.30
Mapstruct 1.5.5.Final
lombok-mapstruct-binding 0.2.0

This is how my annotation processor paths are configured in my pom.xml:
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>21</source>
        <target>21</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

I have a Java record as a DTO that represents a page of results, and having a generic type T (@Builder and @With are Lombok annotations):
@Builder
@With
public record PageDto<T extends BaseDto>(
        int pageNumber,
        int pageSize,
        int pageNumberOfElements,
        long totalElements,
        int totalPages,
        List<T> content
        ) {
    
    public PageDto {
        
        if(content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}

I use Mapstruct to map the Spring interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page to my PageDto as follows:

A base interface for all my mapper:

public interface BaseMapper<M extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto> {

  @Mapping(target = "pageNumber", expression = "java(entity.getNumber())")
    @Mapping(target = "pageSize", expression = "java(entity.getSize())")
    @Mapping(target = "pageNumberOfElements", expression = "java(entity.getNumberOfElements())")
    @Mapping(target = "totalElements", expression = "java(entity.getTotalElements())")
    @Mapping(target = "totalPages", expression = "java(entity.getTotalPages())")
    @Mapping(target = "content", source = "content")
    PageDto<D> toDto(Page<M> entity);
}


And a Mapstruct mapper extending the BaseMapper:

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<UserEntity, UserDto> {}

But the generated Mapstruct code is having a compile-time error: T cannot be resolved to a type.
Bellow is the generated concrete Mapstruct UserMapperImpl:
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {

    @Override
    public PageDto<UserDto> toDto(Page<UserEntity> entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        
        //this line causes a compile-time error: T cannot be resolved to a type
        PageDto.PageDtoBuilder<T> pageDto = PageDto.builder();

        if ( entity.hasContent() ) {
            pageDto.content( userEntityListToBaseDtoList( entity.getContent() ) );
        }

        pageDto.pageNumber( entity.getNumber() );
        pageDto.pageSize( entity.getSize() );
        pageDto.pageNumberOfElements( entity.getNumberOfElements() );
        pageDto.totalElements( entity.getTotalElements() );
        pageDto.totalPages( entity.getTotalPages() );

        return pageDto.build();
    }
}

This is the line generating the error: PageDto.PageDtoBuilder<T> pageDto = PageDto.builder();
It looks like Mapstruct is not resolving the generic type T.
The correct generated code should be PageDto.PageDtoBuilder<UserDto> pageDto = PageDto.builder();
How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.
Searched for some similar issues on internet but found nothing.
EDIT:
I think but I'm not 100% sure, that the generic type T information is lost at some point in the code, since the Builder is a generic static inner class of PageDto<T extends BaseDto>:
public record PageDto<T extends BaseDto>(
        int pageNumber,
        int pageSize,
        int pageNumberOfElements,
        long totalElements,
        int totalPages,
        List<T> content
        ) {

    ...
    
    //generated by Lombok
    //here T does not refer to the outer class generic type T
    //beacause it's a static class
    public static class PageDtoBuilder<T extends BaseDto> {
        ...
    }
}

In this case, is there a configuration to make in Mapstruct to instruct which generic type should be used with the builder?
Is there any other solution to this problem like passing the generic type to use as a parameter of the builder (Class<T>)?

This is because of the way MapStruct generates the code and handles generic types when used with Lombok's @Builder and @With annotations. MapStruct needs to be explicitly informed about the generic type T.
Refactor PageDto to Avoid Direct Use of Lombok's @Builder with Generics.
Lombok's @Builder has known issues with generics. One way to handle this is to create a custom builder like this:
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PageDto<T extends BaseDto> {
    private int pageNumber;
    private int pageSize;
    private int pageNumberOfElements;
    private long totalElements;
    private int totalPages;
    private List<T> content = new ArrayList<>();

    public static <T extends BaseDto> PageDtoBuilder<T> builder() {
        return new PageDtoBuilder<>();
    }

    public static class PageDtoBuilder<T extends BaseDto> {
        private int pageNumber;
        private int pageSize;
        private int pageNumberOfElements;
        private long totalElements;
        private int totalPages;
        private List<T> content;

        PageDtoBuilder() {
        }

        public PageDtoBuilder<T> pageNumber(int pageNumber) {
            this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
            return this;
        }

        public PageDtoBuilder<T> pageSize(int pageSize) {
            this.pageSize = pageSize;
            return this;
        }

        public PageDtoBuilder<T> pageNumberOfElements(int pageNumberOfElements) {
            this.pageNumberOfElements = pageNumberOfElements;
            return this;
        }

        public PageDtoBuilder<T> totalElements(long totalElements) {
            this.totalElements = totalElements;
            return this;
        }

        public PageDtoBuilder<T> totalPages(int totalPages) {
            this.totalPages = totalPages;
            return this;
        }

        public PageDtoBuilder<T> content(List<T> content) {
            this.content = content;
            return this;
        }

        public PageDto<T> build() {
            return new PageDto<>(pageNumber, pageSize, pageNumberOfElements, totalElements, totalPages, content);
        }
    }
}

And then update the mapper:
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<UserEntity, UserDto> {

    @Override
    @Mapping(target = "pageNumber", expression = "java(entity.getNumber())")
    @Mapping(target = "pageSize", expression = "java(entity.getSize())")
    @Mapping(target = "pageNumberOfElements", expression = "java(entity.getNumberOfElements())")
    @Mapping(target = "totalElements", expression = "java(entity.getTotalElements())")
    @Mapping(target = "totalPages", expression = "java(entity.getTotalPages())")
    @Mapping(target = "content", source = "content")
    PageDto<UserDto> toDto(Page<UserEntity> entity);
}

The custom builder pattern ensures that the correct generic type T is used when creating instances of PageDto.
By explicitly defining the mappings in UserMapper, MapStruct can correctly generate the implementation code.

Thanks for your reply.
Lombok does not generate the same builder as the custom one in your example?

I just tested exactly your suggestion with a custom builder, but it gives exactly the same compile error in the generated mapstruct mapper.
